# python skips some file names in a directory when using os.listdir and filtered with an extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have an directory which has .txt files.i need to extract all the file names in that directory to use it for another operation

my problem is os.lisdir function listing all the files in the directory but after i filtered those files with .txt extension it skipes 4 files.
This is what i am doing

```
dir_listing = os.listdir(path)

all_files = []
for item in dir_listing:
    if ".txt" in item:
        all_files.append(item)
return all_files
```

common thing i noticed in those 4 skipped files was names of all 4 files contains _ mark.for ex:customer_details.txt

I cant figure out after filtering out why these 4 files are skipping.any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: where do you filter out something? i just see that you apend all items to `all_files` and then adding them again if they contain `.txt`

Comment: sorry my bad.i have edited the code snippet.

Comment: From your deleted (because bad) answer: "... here i am considering only .txt extension but for some reason specific few files contains .Txt extension but it was shown as .txt" is important information. Consider adding it to your question, as it is a strong hint to what is gping wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You have `append` twice. BTW, if you just want to check subfix, use `endswith` method instead of `in`.

```
import os
path = './'
dir_listing = os.listdir(path)
all_files = []
for item in dir_listing:
    if item.endswith(".txt"):
        all_files.append(item)


print(all_files)
```

**Update**
My files and its structure:

```
landpacks-MacBook-Pro:xk  tree
.
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
├── c.txtaa
├── d.py
├── e.txt
└── xk.py

0 directories, 6 files
landpacks-MacBook-Pro:xk  python xk.py 
['b.txt', 'a.txt', 'e.txt']
```

Comment: no luck still the same behaviour.also another file is skipping when i use endswith.any idea why its skipping the file names?

Comment: Can you run `tree` in your work directory, so that we can see what files you have?

Comment: i did run the tree in my work directory but it's hard to post here as i have a long structure.what exactly do you want to know about the files?

Comment: @Akalanka I just want to make sure you have assign the right `path`.

Comment: yea i am quite sure path is right.reason to wonder is in the directory where i am retrieving file names have lot with .txt extension but only four is skipping.all other file names i can retrieve

Comment: Can you print out each `item`?

Comment: yea i have printed out each item to check whether os.lisdir lists all the file names.and yes it does,problem arises when i  filtering with   if ".txt" in item: